# jQuery timepicker and jQuery datepair: setting a maximum duration (delta)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, timepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using jQuery timepicker and jQuery datepair to set up an appointment creation page. I want to limit the total duration of the appointment to 3 hours or whatever. I am having trouble figuring out how to enforce this.

html:

```
<div id="dateTimePicker">
    <input type="text" class="date start"/>
    <input type="text" class="time start"/> to
    <input type="text" class="time end" id="timeEnd"/>
    <input type="text" class="date end"/>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('#dateTimePicker .time').timepicker({
        'minTime': '6:00am',
        'maxTime': '11:00pm',
        'step': 15,
        'showDuration': true,
        'timeFormat': 'g:ia'
    }).on('changeTime', function (e) {
        var milliseconds = datepair.getTimeDiff();
        // is the time more than 3 hours?
        if (milliseconds > 10800000) {
            console.log('time too big')
            $('#dateTimePicker').timepicker('setTime', '10:15am');
        }
    });
```

I thought I could just check on the changeTime event, however that gets triggered one click after it happens. eg. if I change the time to have a delta of 4 hours the event won't get called until I change it again to something over the range I am looking for.

Even after that I still am not sure how to set the end time. In the documentation for jQuery timepicker it says you can use 'setTime' however it is unclear what to do when a datepair is used.

I just want to enforce a maximum duration of the time interval and I am not sure how

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vmjo1aw6/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `blur` is the event you're looking for, i.e., change

```
.on('changeTime', function (e)
```

to

```
.on('blur', function (e)
```

Comment: that event does solve the problems I was having with changeTime being one behind. I am still not sure about how to properly change the end time though

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I didn't notice the other question.
Anyway, it depends on what you want to when the user exceeds the time limit.
One solution that I like is that when the user focuses on the end time ('focus' event), save the original value that was there. Once the 3 hour limit is exceeded, revert back to the original time that was written there (and was valid).
Look here: https://jsfiddle.net/vmjo1aw6/4/